# Populate SharePoint Group from BCS external List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, bcs

I have a BCS External List that is giving me the data that I want.  Currently that data is usernames (domain\username).

Is there anyway to sync/import/connect an External List with a SharePoint Group?

I would like to have the users from the external list appear within a SharePoint group for purposes of permissions and target audiences.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no Out-Of-The-Box solution.
You have to code a SharePoint job that will synchronise the External list with the SharePoint Group.